# Accepting values containing multiple point system

Tags: php, mysql, database, floating-point

How do i accept values from user that contain multiple points like 1.2.1...if i use float--1.2.1 gets converted to 1.2.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends... Does `1.2.1` have a meaning as number? And, if so, what meaning?

Answer (score 3):

the simple answer: *if u want multiple points **DONT USE FLOAT** :-)*

use something like varchar or text instead

Comment: +1, no way to store it other than text, because "1.2.1" is not a valid number (at least, not in our numbering system), it's a numerically encoded data field.

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as text.

A float is used to represent Real numbers, and "1.2.1" is not a Real number.

Or, if "1.2.1" is simply a grouping of numbers, you could split the input of "1.2.1" into three separate numbers using the period as a delimiter, and store them as distinct numbers.